# .htaccess : Redirect all sites on my joomla website to root/main domain except one

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, joomla

So I really don't know what I'm doing wrong here, but I'm not too familiar with .htaccess stuff. What I want to do is to redirect every sub-site on my webspace to the main/root domain, except for one specific page which would be " my-website.de/impressum-datenschutz ".

This is what I got

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/impressum-datenschutz$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://my-website.de/ [R=301,L]
```

While the first part, redirecting from www to non-www works just fine, when I insert the second part, i get an error in my webbrowser telling me " this website redirects the request in a way so that it can never be finished" (roughly translated from German) .

What am I doing wrong?

Really thankful for any kind of help

Answer (score 0):

For non-www to www use this

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.yourdomain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.yourdomain.com/ [L,R=301]
```

For redirect all subdomains to domain try this

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^yourdomain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://yourdomain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```